# How Can I Automatically Create Profile For Guest User During PIN Activation

Tags: python, django

I am working on an Event Ticketing Application in Django where guest would need a Recharge PIN to be validated on the portal for booking or reserving a seat in an event they bought PIN for. And I also want these guests to be authenticated so I can be able to management Authorization on them too.

In my Models I have a Profile Model where I am using signals to automatically create user profile upon Admin User Creation, and I also have three User Groups  in the Create New User Form with Privileges assigned accordingly; Organizer, Staff and Guest are the groups. I have also developed a Django CreateUserForm class using UserCreationForm module in my forms.py where I have a Drop Down of all these group for the Admin to add Users (Registration Page is accessible by Admin only) using Admin dashboard.

My problem is that I want each PIN that is Validated by Guest to be able to create his/her Profile immediately the PIN Validated using Signals but I don't know how to do it.

I am confused with my CreateUserForm class since all the groups are listed in Drop down. Don't know how to use conditionals inside the form to determine whether it is PIN activation from a Guest so that Guest Group will be the only option and once it is Admin all the User Groups would be populated.

Below is my Profile Model code:

```
GENDER = (
('Male', 'Male'),
('Female', 'Female'),
)
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    othernames = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    image = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', blank=False, null=False, upload_to ='profile_images', 

)
```

Here is my User Creation Form code:

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(),
                               required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'group']
```

Here is my Pin Activation in the views.py:

```
def pin_activation(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    
    #Create new form with name form
    form = PinActivationForm(request.POST)

    #Check if the the form has valid data in it
    if form.is_valid():

        #Check the status of the user Pin with the one in the Database
        check_pin_status = Pin.objects.filter(value=form['pin'].value(), status='Not Activated')

        #Check with the Status of the Pin is Right
        if check_pin_status:

            #Update the User Pin with a new status
            Pin.objects.filter(value=form['pin'].value()).update(status='Activated')
            #Message the User
            messages.success(request, 'Pin Activated Successfully')
            #Redirect the user
            return redirect('user-register')
 
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Pin Already Activated.You are Logged In.')
            return redirect('guest-index')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Something Went Wrong. Try again')
else:
    form = PinActivationForm()
context = {
    'form':form,
}
return render(request, 'user/pin_activation.html', context)
```

Someone should graciously assist with the best way of handling this kind of issue. Thanks

Comment: Can you share your Pin model?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by adding a registration form immediately after pin action so that guest would register using user and password, then using the same profile signal the guess profile is automatically created.
Here is the code:

```
def pin_activation(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    
    #Create new form with name form
    form = PinActivationForm(request.POST)

    #Check if the the form has valid data in it
    if form.is_valid():

        #Check the status of the user Pin with the one in the Database
        check_pin_status = Pin.objects.filter(value=form['pin'].value(), status='Not Activated')

        #Check if the PIN is correct and NOT ACTIVATED
        if check_pin_status:

            #Update the User Pin with a new status of Activated
            Pin.objects.filter(value=form['pin'].value()).update(status='Activated')
            #Message the User
            messages.success(request, 'Pin Activated Successfully')
            #Redirect the user
            return redirect('register-guest')
 
        elif Pin.objects.filter(value=form['pin'].value(), status="Activated"):
            messages.error(request, 'Pin Already Activated.')
            return redirect('user-profile-update')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid PIN")
            return redirect('user-login')
            
               
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Something Went Wrong. Try again')
else:
    form = PinActivationForm()
context = {
    'form':form,
}
return render(request, 'user/pin_activation.html', context)
```

Guest Registration Function

```
def register_guest(request):
#Create variable and query all users
workers = User.objects.all()
page_title = "Event Guest Register"
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = GuestUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Registered Successfully.')
        return redirect('dashboard-index')
else:
    form = GuestUserForm()
context = {
    'form':form,
    'workers':workers,
    'page_title':page_title,
}
return render(request, 'user/register.html', context)
```

Guest User Registration Form in forms.py

```
class GuestUserForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField
#Get Guest Group from DB
group = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Group.objects.filter(name='Guest'),
    initial=Group.objects.filter(name='Guest'),
    disabled=True
)


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'group']
```

My PIN Model

```
class Pin(models.Model):
ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
value = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=generate_pin, blank=True)
added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,  blank=False)
reference = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, editable = False, default=uuid.uuid4)
status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Not Activated')
#Save Reference Number
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     self.reference == str(uuid.uuid4())
     super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.ticket

class Meta:
    unique_together = ["ticket", "value"]

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.ticket} | {self.value}"
```

The only Issue I am having now is that whenever a Guest Activates a Pin but could not proceeds with Registration or does not completes the registration form and logs out or closes the browser then, His/Her Pin would be showing Pin Already Activated and since I am using Login Required Decorator on the Update Profile Function then he is not allowed to Update his/her profile because he is not a user yet even though the activation function is redirecting the guest to update his or her profile.

What is the logic that would make sure that any PIN activation without User Registration is not yet Valid PIN Activation or what is the best solution for this use case.